# Running gulp from cmd works but not in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webstorm

I have a project which is using gulp to run everything.
When I do `gulp run`from the command line everything works fine.
However when I set up the project in WebStorm to run with gulp it does not work.
Node seems not to be found:

`sh: 1: node: not found events.js:168 throw err;`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution eventually.
My node is installed at 
`~/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.3/bin/node` 
This is also configured in WebStorm, however somehow when running the the gulp task it looks at `/usr/bin/node`.

So to solve I made a symbolic link to my node install:

`sudo ln -s ~/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.3/bin/node /usr/bin/node`

This solved my problem.